# Save foreign key in django model by value of other field

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm dealing with apples and buckets imported from an API. They shall be written into a Django database using the models.

The Rest API holds an ID of buckets which isn't the internal one but saved as `external_id` in the local Bucket Model.

The local Apple Model has a field `bucket` which is a `models:ForeignKey(Bucket)` field.

When retrieving and storing the data I can't find out how to connect those two. Is there a way to simply have Django query for the external_id on the bucket table and then use the resulting row to connect the Foreign Key?

```
a = Apple(
    'name' = apple.name
    'count' =  apple.count
    'bucket' = ???
)

a.save()
```

Comment: Good idea to also add `unique=True` on the `bucket.external_id` field. This will add an index that will check uniqueness AND speed up queries on this field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do the following:

```
a = Apple(name=..., count=...)  # note there are no quotes around the field names here
a.bucket = Bucket.objects.get(external_id=external_id_from_your_rest_api)
a.save()
```

Comment: thanks, don't know how the single quotes got in there but there are none in my code - thanks for helping out!